# How to use transform.from_bounds from Rasterio in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, raster, rasterio

I'm trying to set the bounds from some koordinates: xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, using Rasterio and transform.from_bounds.

I set it like this

`transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, 0.00028, 0.00028)`

The problem is that when i print metadata or bounds, the bounds are not set according to transform, and is just Affine(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, -1.0, 0.0).
How do I set this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, don't be afraid of Affine. It is just another representation.

The only thing I'm confused with in your code is width and height (i.e. the number of pixels). Your value `0.00028` looks like a resolution. The proper way to define it:

```
bbox_size = (height, width)
bbox = [left, bottom, right, top]
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(
        *bbox, width=bbox_size[1], height=bbox_size[0]
    )
```